# Как сверстать такой блок с box-shadow или с помощью других атрибутов CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, `box-shadow` виден только начиная с середины блока, и снизу тени больше, чем у краев.  Форма границ не ровная, с выпуклостями, поэтому затруднительно точно воспроизвести её с помощью CSS.
В векторном редакторе нарисована эта криволинейная форма. См. ниже.

Как сверстать такой блок с box-shadow или с помощью других атрибутов CSS или SVG?

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="411" height="519" viewBox="0 10 411 519" >  
    <path  fill="#fff" stroke="#CDCDCD" stroke-width="3"  class="shadow"
     d="M390.2 2.7V30c0 0 5.6 7.8 5.5 12.3-0.6 20.8-1.4 53.2-1.4 53.2l-5.5 57.3v98.2l4.1 23.2-6.8 36.8c0 0 5.2 109.8 2.7 156.9-0.3 6.5 2.5 25.9-19.1 25.9-111.6 0.3-210.5 0-322 0-10.7 0-19-15.2-19.1-25.9-0.4-31 0-102.3 0-102.3l-4.1-23.2c0 0-4.1-11-2.7-16.4 1.5-5.6 10.8-7.8 10.9-13.6C34.4 224.9 30 15 30 15V0.7L377.9 2Z"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: to ALL Доработан вопрос. Мне показался он интересным для отвечающих и участникам, изучающих CSS, SVG.  После внесенных изменений вопрос будет полезен для базы знаний. Прошу поддержать переоткрытие вопроса, иначе он через какое-то время исчезнет

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вопрос не исчезнет, т.к. у него уже есть ответы с положительным рейтингом. Добавлять свой код в вопрос не было необходимости

Answer (score 5):

Так как края прямоугольника неровные, с выступами, то лучше использовать SVG для повторения формы краев прямоугольника.

Тень можно создавать, как фильтрами CSS, так и SVG

### Вариант CSS

```css
.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2));
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2));
 }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="411" height="519" viewBox="0 10 411 519" >  
    <path  fill="#fff"  class="shadow"
     d="M390.2 2.7V30c0 0 5.6 7.8 5.5 12.3-0.6 20.8-1.4 53.2-1.4 53.2l-5.5 57.3v98.2l4.1 23.2-6.8 36.8c0 0 5.2 109.8 2.7 156.9-0.3 6.5 2.5 25.9-19.1 25.9-111.6 0.3-210.5 0-322 0-10.7 0-19-15.2-19.1-25.9-0.4-31 0-102.3 0-102.3l-4.1-23.2c0 0-4.1-11-2.7-16.4 1.5-5.6 10.8-7.8 10.9-13.6C34.4 224.9 30 15 30 15V0.7L377.9 2Z"  />
</svg>
```

### Вариант SVG

```html
<style>
.shadow {
  filter:url(#dropshadow);
 }
</style>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="411" height="519" viewBox="0 10 411 519" > 
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="10"/> 
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="6" result="offsetblur"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.2"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>        
        
    <path  fill="#fff"  class="shadow"
     d="M390.2 2.7V30c0 0 5.6 7.8 5.5 12.3-0.6 20.8-1.4 53.2-1.4 53.2l-5.5 57.3v98.2l4.1 23.2-6.8 36.8c0 0 5.2 109.8 2.7 156.9-0.3 6.5 2.5 25.9-19.1 25.9-111.6 0.3-210.5 0-322 0-10.7 0-19-15.2-19.1-25.9-0.4-31 0-102.3 0-102.3l-4.1-23.2c0 0-4.1-11-2.7-16.4 1.5-5.6 10.8-7.8 10.9-13.6C34.4 224.9 30 15 30 15V0.7L377.9 2Z"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Для `box-shadow` укажите `<offset-y>`.

```css
.box-shadow {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-shadow"></div>
```

Подробнее о [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)